# How does more than one thread execute on a processor core

Tags: multithreading, cpu, multicore

I wanted to know how does a multi-threaded program with more number of threads executes on a processor core. For example, my program has 12 threads and I am running it on a intel core-i5 machine. It has four CPUs. Will each core run 3 threads? I am confused because I have seen programs with 30 threads running on a 4 core machine.

Thanks

Comment: The same way that multiple processes run: timesharing.

Comment: On most non embedded devices your kernel sets up an interrupt to fire after a certain time, then loads one of your threads and runs in userspace, then when the interrupt fires, the interrupt handler goes back into kernel space, the kernel then sometimes switches to another thread, sets up the interrupt again. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each core would be able to execute one thread simultaneously. So if there are 30 threads and 4 cores, 26 threads will be waiting to get context switched to get executed. Something like, thread 1-4 runs for 200ms and then 5-8 runs for 200 ms and so on

Comment: Ok! I get it. So basically, OS scheduler or kernel comes into play then?

Comment: @user225008 yes indeed

Comment: @Steve do you suggest any book to dig into this?

Comment: @NandoSousa just google operating system kernel. You do need to spend a fair amount of time if you want a full understanding of how the OS works.

Comment: He means 4 Cores right, he by mistake wrote 4 CPU in ques, can you correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

The processor core is capable of executing one thread at a time. In a quad core, 4 threads are executed simultaneously. Not all the user space threads are executed simultaneously, the kernel threads also runs to schedule the next thread or do some other kernel tasks.